# How does a database locate a record using clustered index?

Tags: database, performance, indexing

In a non-clustered index, each entry is of fixed length and so the database may use binary search to locate the record address in O(nlogn) time.

Since the tables have variable length records, and clustered index uses the underlying table itself for search (or am I wrong?) , how does the database find a record for a specific key in O(nlogn) time?

Answer (score 0):

> each entry is of fixed length

Not true for real-world databases.

Rows are split into groups called pages. Pages have a fixed size (~8KB). They form a tree structure with the top levels linking to the physical location of the bottom level pages.

That allows the tree to be traversed top-to-bottom, entering the relevant branch at each step.

Clustered indexes typically have exactly the same physical structure as non-clustered indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Just to ensure I am following you correctly.  When I say the entry is fixed length, I am referring to one entry in the index - corresponding to one tuple / record in the table.  If I understand you correctly, I think you are telling the entire table is divided into multiple 8KB pages, organized in a tree structure.  Aren't we talk about two different things?

Comment: Per the following web page, leaf layer of a nonclustered index is made up of index pages whereas that of clustered index is made up of data pages.  I was implying in my question that index page entries are of fixed length and data page entries are of variable length.   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484(v=sql.105).aspx]

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan all pages are of fixed length and all rows are of variable length. You say "When I say the entry is fixed length, I am referring to one entry in the index" - no. You can index varchar fields and they will be variable length.; Using the tree structure, the engine can find the page of any record in log N time. The page contains a sorted array of 2-byte offsets into the page that represent the starts of each row. That allows for binary search inside of each page.